# Exception handling, Is this example good practice?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I mainly use the Try Catch in exception handling.. and use **Exit Sub** to terminate the method

In this code example:

What should be done to prevent Redundant code (i.e. commit and close connection)

```
'connect to DB

  Try

    'insert / update statement

  Catch ex as Exception

   'rollback
   'commit
   'closeDBConnection
      Exit Sub

  End Try

'commit
'close DBconnection
```

Is using Exit Sub a good practice ?

Comment: Couldn't you use finally to do this?

Comment: my question is wouldn't exit sub ignore the finally block?

Comment: No. `Exit sub/return` don't interrupt `try-finally`. `Finally` will complete still

Comment: @T.S. thank you for explaining. this is what i'm looking for. can you put this as an answer and provide reference if any. so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exit sub`/`return`, or exception that occur **within** `try` - don't bypass `finally` block. Finally will complete still.

See this for full explanation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Put the commit statement at the end of Try block. Also use Finally block to do some cleanup.

```
Try
    ' insert / update statement
    ' commit
Catch ex As Exception
    ' rollback
Finally
    ' close DB connection
End Try
```

Comment: plus for suggesting to use Finally Block and for a fast answer